# Filter and Join tables in MY SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, yii2

I have two tables Table1 and Table2
In Table 1 column mobile has multiple entries of Mobile number.
I want to get the id of those repeating mobile number from table1 and search that ids of table1 in table2 where clientId = table1.id.

I tried the below SQL code for obtaining id of repeating mobile number

```
SELECT id  FROM table1  GROUP BY mobile  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

then I tried feeding the values into a new array where table1.id = table2.clientId

```
foreach ($table1data as $key) {
        $items[] = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand("

        SELECT clientId 
        FROM table2  
        WHERE clientId = :cid

        ")
        ->bindValue(':cid',$key['id'])
        ->queryAll();
    }
```

Comment: i think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51284947/join-tables-using-model-in-yii2/51285906#51285906) answer is usefull

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Join tables using model in Yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51284947/join-tables-using-model-in-yii2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `table1 (id)` has identical value then you can use `INNER JOIN` with `EXISTS` :

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2 inner join
     table1 t1
     on t1.id = t2.clientId 
where not exists (select 1 from table1 t11 where t11.mobile = t1.mobile and t11.id <> t.id);
```